# Relation between transitivity and intermediate fields of splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and $f(x) \in \mathbb{K}[x]$ is separable. Consider $\mathbb{E}$ is an intermediate field between $\mathbb{F}$, a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{K}$, and $\mathbb{K}$. Is it true that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{E}$ if and only if $Aut_{\mathbb{E}}\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of $S_n\ ; n=deg(f)$? (Here $Aut_{\mathbb{E}}\mathbb{F}$ means the set of all field automorphism $\mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ which fixes $\mathbb{E}$ elementwise.)

My proof:

Let's say $Aut_{\mathbb{E}}\mathbb{F}$ is transitive if it is isomorphic to a transitive subgroup. Consider $ \{ u_1,\cdots,u_n \} $ to be roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}$.

Suppose $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb{E}$, then $f=gh$ ($deg(h) \ge 1$) is decomposed over $\mathbb{E}$. Now, for all $\sigma \in Aut_{\mathbb{E}}\mathbb{F}$, $\sigma$ fixes $g$. Hence, there is no map in $ Aut_{\mathbb{E}}\mathbb{F}$ which sends a root of $g$ to a root of $h$. Hence, $Aut_{\mathbb{E}}\mathbb{F}$ is not transitive.

For the reverse, if $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{E}$, there is an $\mathbb{E}$-isomorphism $\sigma: \mathbb{E}(u_i) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(u_j)$ such that $\sigma(u_i)=u_j$ for every $i,j$. Moreover, $\mathbb{F}$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{K}$ implies $\mathbb{F}$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{E}$. Hence, $\sigma$ can be extended to $\mathbb{F}$, that is $\sigma \in Aut_{\mathbb{E}}\mathbb{F}$. Hence, $Aut_{\mathbb{E}}\mathbb{F}$ is transitive.

Is everything correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct, I would have added that $\mathbb{E}(u_i)$ and $\mathbb{E}(u_j)$ are **the** rupture field of $f$ since it is irreducible so that's why there an $\mathbb{E}$-isomorphism between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a little more careful. As it is stated, the result is actually false. For example, let $K=E=\mathbb Q$ and $f=(X^2-2)(X^2-3)$. Then $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ and the Galois group is $V=(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$. Of course, this is isomorphic to a *non-transitive* subgroup of $S_4$ using the action on the roots of $f$, so having generators $(12)$ and $(34)$.

However, the Galois group is also isomorphic to a *transitive* subgroup of $S_4$, using the generators $(12)(34)$ and $(13)(24)$. We can regard this as the action on the conjugates of the primitive element $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$.

In general, every finite Galois extension has a primitive element, and hence the Galois group is always isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of a symmetric group.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you. Now, how can I make the statement correct? One way is to add the condition that elements of $Aut_{\mathbb{K}}\mathbb{F}$ permute $ \{ u_1,\cdots,u_n \} $. Am I correct?